# how to pass table value to viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I am taking few values like username, userfullname, userid, userlogin from databse. In current scene checking all this details in `page_load`, its hitting database several times. to avoid this want to get all these values at the same time and store them in viewstate to use it multiple times without hitting server for that session.
How to pass table row values to the viewstate?
using VS2010, coding in asp.net 3.5 with sql server 2008.

Comment: I assume you're mixing up session and ViewState since you're saying that you want to use `ViewState` to use it multiple times for that `Session`. ViewState is just for the current request(page+user) whereas session is for the current user across all requests. I would chose Session in this case. Store a custom object(f.e. a class `User` with all these properties) in the session.

Answer (score 0):

just store your data row in viewstate

```
ViewState["UserdetailRow"] = DataTable.Row[0];
```

to get it back

```
   if(ViewState["UserdetailRow"] != null)
     DataRow dr = ViewState["UserdetailRow"] as DataRow;
```